# Restore mysql lost table

Tags: mysql, backup, database-restore

I accidentally deleted a table in my mysql database. After that I've restored this table from backup which is scheduled daily at 00:01. But there are lost data from 00:01 to 12:34. Is there a way to restore these records? Table engine is myisam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, the data between your scheduled backup and the removal is lost unless you performed some other backup routines or did some query logging in that timeframe

Comment: There are no any other backups. I don't know what query logging is. If you mean any open resultset no I don't have it either.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik there is a backup mechanism if you had enabled the log of all queries. If you didn't, the data is lost forever.

Comment: Actualy I'm not sure if queries are logged. Where does MySql store logged queries?
Thanks..

Comment: That depends on your operation system and on you configuration. Check your config file (mostly my.cnf) for more information.